# How to test if an attribute inside Jest 'resolves' result has some value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a method that returns a promise that resolves to an object like:

```
{ email: 'an@email.com', otherValue: 'otherValue'}
```

Then I've written a test for it:

```
test('myFunction should build information correctly', () => {
    return expect(myFunction()).resolves.email.toBe('an@email.com');
});
```

If I do `resolves.toBe('an@email')`, of course I receive an error because it isn't:

```
{ email: 'an@email.com', otherValue: 'otherValue'}
```

But if I try to access the *email* attribute I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBe' of undefined
```

What am I missing?, because resolves is not a promise (it doesn't have a then method).

Answer (score 2):

Use `expect(myFunction()).resolves.toHaveProperty("email", "an@email.com");` because `resolves` is not your promises resolve value, it is a Jest object.

Comment: I get "TypeError: expect(...).resolves.objectContaining is not a function"

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda My bad, is actually `toHaveProperty` instead of `objectContaining`. I've edited my answer